# Can't read the tag using Pycomm3 from a LogixController Simulator

Tags: python-3.x, ethernet, plc

I have simulated a controllogix controller using the library CPPPO.

Command -

```
enip_server -v SCADA=INT[1000] TEXT=SSTRING[100] FLOAT=REAL
```

**Output** -
[image]

I want to use pycomm3 library to read and write the tags, as you can see above three tags have created by cpppo while starting the simulation server - SCADA, TEXT and FLOAT, i just want to read any one of them.
Here is the code I'm using -

```
from pycomm3 import LogixDriver

with LogixDriver('127.0.0.1') as plc:
    print(plc)
    # plc.write('TEXT', 'Hello World!')
    print(plc.read('TEXT'))
```

**Output** -
[image]

The logs in CPPPO Server are -
[image]

Instead of **Tags doesn't exist** , we should receive the value of TEXT Tag

Answer (score 1):

So, there is a couple things going on here.  The main 'feature' of pycomm3 is how it handles everything automatically for you, but for it to do that it needs to first upload the tag list from the PLC.  It looks like CPPPO doesn't implement those services, if you enable the [logging](https://docs.pycomm3.dev/en/latest/getting_started.html#logging) you will see that it errors out when trying to upload the tag list. (I think this error should have bubbled up and exited the `with` block before ever trying to read the tag - I will get it changed in the next release)  You can bypass this though by defining your own `_initialize_driver` method and setting the tag list manually:

```
from pycomm3 import SHORT_STRING, REAL  # also need to import the CIP types

def _cpppo_initialize_driver(self, _, __):
    self._cfg['use_instance_ids'] = False  # force it to only use the tag name in requests
    self._info = self.get_plc_info()  # optional

    self._tags = {
        'TEXT': {
            'tag_name': 'TEXT',
            'tag_type': 'atomic',
            'data_type_name': 'SHORT_STRING',
            'data_type': 'SHORT_STRING',
            'dim': 1,
            'dimensions': [100, 0, 0],
            'type_class': SHORT_STRING,
        },
        'FLOAT': {
            'tag_name': 'FLOAT',
            'tag_type': 'atomic',
            'data_type_name': 'REAL',
            'data_type': 'REAL',
            'dim': 0,
            'dimensions': [0, 0, 0],
            'type_class': REAL,
        }
    }

LogixDriver._initialize_driver = _cpppo_initialize_driver
```

The `_tags` attribute is a dict of the tag name to the definition for the tag, [this](https://docs.pycomm3.dev/en/latest/usage/logixdriver.html#tags-and-data-types) section in the docs has a lot more details about what each field is for.  The examples I added are simple atomic tags, if you want to do structs it is a little more complicated.

In addition to that, I did find a bug dealing with the `write` method.  Currently, it is including part of the request twice in the packet.  Real PLCs seems to ignore this, but CPPPO doesn't handle it and leads to an error. I have a fix already in my development branch and can confirm both reads and writes will work.  Unfortunately, I have a few other changes in progress that I need to get done before I release a new version.  If you follow the repo on [GitHub](https://github.com/ottowayi/pycomm3) it will notify you when it is released.  If writes are critical and waiting for a fix is not possible, I can give you the fix since it's fairly small.

Comment: I am still facing the same error even after initializing our own driver.